# How to query another Django model in template view based on the relation to another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have these models

```
class Protocol(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Description(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    protocol = models.ForeignKey(Protocol)

class Trait(models.Model):
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    protocol = models.ForeignKey(Protocol)

class State(models.Model):
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    trait = models.ForeignKey(Trait)

class Expression(models.Model):
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)
    description = models.ForeignKey(Description)
```

So a *Protocol* (e.g. protocol "A") consist of a certain amount of *Traits* (e.g. height, weight, color). Each *Trait* can have multiple *States* (e.g. low, medium, high). Then, a *Description* is a collection of *Expressions* related to a specific *Protocol*. For example Description #1 is made with Protocol "A" and consist of two Expressions: height -> low, weight -> high; but Trait color is not specified.

Basically, what i want to do is display in a template view **all** the *Traits* linked to the specific Protocol of the selected Description, and then the corresponding *Expression* which can also be empty for some *Trait*.

Like this:

```
| Trait  | Expression |
|--------+------------|
| height |            |
| weight | high       |
| color  | blue       |
```

Using the shell i can easily return what i need

```
# Select a Description
desc = Description.objects.first()

# Get the protocol
protocol = desc.protocol

# Get all traits in the selected protocol
all_traits = protocol.trait_set.all()

# Get all the expressions in this description
expressions = desc.expression_set.all()

# Print all traits within the selected protocol and their related expression (if any)
for trait in all_traits:
    print(trait.desc)
    expr = expressions.filter(state__trait_id = trait.id).first()
    print(expr.state.desc)
```

However, I can't figure out how to do it in a view, especially I would like continue using a DetailView, but it's not a strict requirement if not possible.
Is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this, even though I'm not completely satisfied because I feel it is not a very elegant solution.

I created a `description_extras.py` in a `templatetags/` directory inside my app (do not forget the `__init__.py` to treat it as a package)

Inside `description_extras.py` I've created a custom filter, like this:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def expr_trait(expression,trait_id):
    return expression.filter(state__trait_id = trait_id).first()
```

Then in the template, I load the custom filter with

```
{% load description_extras %}
```

And then I can call the filter like this:

```
{% for trait in description.protocol.trait_set.all %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ trait.desc }}</td>
        <td>{{ description.expression_set.all|expr_trait:trait.id }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```